# How to use async and await to turn an active (Pull-) Parser into a passive Push-Parser?

Tags: c#, parsing, async-await

I have a Parser Method that returns the Position of the first Match with _Pattern. Unfortunately it is actively pulling for the Characters. I would like it to be passive, driven by Characters given, so that I can have multiple Parsers 'concurrently' searching for different Patterns on the same Stream and return the first one that fits. It should look about like this:

```
Task<int>[] patterns = new Task<int>[] { };
var patternNo = Task.WaitAny(patterns);
var pattern1 = patterns[patternNo];
var found = pattern1.Result;
```

This is the Method in "Pull"-Mode, reading the Characters with Func:

```
public int IndexIn(Func<char> reader) {
var currItem = reader();
for (int i, p = i = 0; ;) {
    if (p == -1 || _Pattern[p] == currItem) {
        ++i; ++p;
        currItem = reader();
    } else {
        p = _Prefix[p]; 
    }
    if (p >= _Pattern.Length) {
        return i - _Pattern.Length;
    }
}
```

I can easily convert it to a Push-driven Method using async/await, that is the beauty of this Framework:

```
public async Task<int> IsFound(Task<char> nextChar) {
    var currItem = await nextChar;
    for (int i, p = i = 0; ;) {
        if (p == -1 || _Pattern[p] == currItem) {
            ++i; ++p;
            currItem = await nextChar;
        } else {
            p = _Prefix[p]; 
        }
        if (p >= _Pattern.Length) {
            return i - _Pattern.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I 'drive' this asynchronous Method? I would need to construct a Task that delivers the Characters to it. Given a String I would like to feed it to the Patterns like so:

```
var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<char>();
var isFound = searcher.IsFound(completion.Task);
foreach(var chr in stringToSearchIn) {
    completion.SetResult(chr);
    if (isFound.IsCompleted) {
        break;
    }
}
return isFound.Result;
```

But TaskCompletionSource stays Complete, even after the Result was retrieved. Can I reset it? Is there an alternative Class I can use or do I have to write my own custom TaskCompletionSource? Or are Tasks intended to be single-shot/Value only?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't reuse a `Task` that way.  The `Task` represents a single action to take, once it returns its result, it is done.

Comment: Your trying to misuse a task as some sort of a message queue. Better yous a real stream, which pipes new data in each parser

Comment: This is a problem way more suited for Rx

Comment: @Jesse Carter That is an interesting idea, how would it look like with Rx? I suppose I would need to implement public void OnNext(char value) {...} but that is hard, because I would have to break up the intricate Logic in IsFound(). 
That is why I consider using async, because I can keep the Code Structure.

Comment: Yeah I imagine you would have a source stream of characters with multiple output observables as your parsers acting on the stream and then you could use a higher level operator like race to find the first one that gets a match https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html

Comment: @Jesse Carter The goal is the same as with Rx: I want to minimize Processing and stop as soon as the first Parser found a Match, but implementing OnNext(char chr) would be hard for me, because I would have to rewrite the IsFound() Method and turn it 'inside out' around the reader() Call. And this is a relatively simple Parser Function, imagine a more complex, multi-level Parser or multiple reader() Calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your efforts. What I'm trying to achieve here is an Inversion of Control Flow and that is what yield and also async/await are made for. They build a State machine that can return directly after the 'yield' or 'await' Command. 'yield' returns Values, 'await' retrieves Values, so using these Constructs you can switch Control Flow both in Read-Scenarios as well as in Write-Scenarios. 
In this case I can provide a Task-Factory that creates a new Task for each Character I want to consume:

```
public class TaskFactory<T> {
    public TaskCompletionSource<T> Task { get; private set; }

    public Task<T> GetTask() {
        Task = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        return Task.Task;
    }
}
```

The following Client-Code works as intended then:

```
var completion = new TaskFactory<char>();
var isFound = searcher.IsFound(completion.GetTask);
foreach(var chr in hayStack) {
    completion.Task.SetResult(chr);
    if (isFound.IsCompleted) {
        break;
    }
}
return isFound.Result;
```

This creates some Overhead though, which makes it slower than the synchronous Push-Operation:

1. Parser: creating the TaskCompletionSource
2. Parser: storing the resume Information on await
3. Driver: filling the current TaskCompletionSource thus signaling
   Completion
4. Parser: resuming Control Flow